# What is the way to get bot-java lib from maven central

Tags: java, android, maven, botframework

**Missing maven central artifact** `com.microsoft.bot:bot-java:4.6.0-preview2` within Android project.

Maven central search for artifacts: [check here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.microsoft.bot)

all those artifacts depend on `com.microsoft.bot.bot-java` artifact which is not available there and when included into Android project 
we have got:
**ERROR: Failed to resolve: `com.microsoft.bot:bot-java:4.6.0-preview2`**

my build.gradle dependency includes:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.bot:bot-connector:4.6.0-preview2'
```

Is that parent pom artifact missing by mistake there?

Comment: If it's not in Maven Central, you'll have to find a public repo that does expose it.  If that can't be had, you'll have to mvn:install it in your local .m2 manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent POM has been published and should be good to go.  Apologies for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like they made a mistake. They should have deployed the parent POM as well.

It is available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/blob/master/pom.xml) if you want to manually install to your local .m2. Otherwise, you will need to wait for them to fix it.

I've [raised a GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/issues/120) for you.

Comment: Hihi! Please do not forget that the java bot is currently in PREVIEW, and being actively worked on by the team.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes sure, but prior to the fix there was nothing to preview but a broken build